# Struggling to power a 20 W COB LED

Tags: led, cob

I am not an engineer and have minimal electronics experience.

I am trying to build a projector for an art project and ordered a 20 W LED, a voltage regulator and a 15 V DC power supply.

No matter what, the LED does not turn on.

I tested the power supply using a small blue LED which turned on when I applied about 3 - 4 V.

I don't know if I got a broken LED or fried it while setting it up.

[image]

I am using the following parts:

1. [Regulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078Q1624B)
2. [LED](https://www.ebay.com/itm/126302257737?var=427340013933)
3. [Power Supply](https://www.ebay.com/itm/115310388578)

Could anyone help solve my problem?

Comment: Please link the datasheets for the components you have purchased.

Comment: @vir just added but can't find the data sheets so put the links to where I got them. Am looking for sheets.

Comment: What voltage does the COB LED need exactly? I don't see it listed, so how did you decide on 15v?

Comment: @user1850479 I literally dont know. I didnt see it listed either so google what voltage for 20w led and it said 10-11, and I can keep it down to that with the regulator but it doesn't turn on. I started at 3V and increased until it stopped at 14.8V and no light and no current reading. I tested on a smaller led and found that it turned on and the current was measured so that board seems to work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @emp That's why we don't buy electronics components without datasheets. And probably not from Ebay or aliexpress etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's not unusual for this kind of 20W **white** LED to require 30-36VDC. So for it to not turn on with only 15V is not surprising at all. LEDs are very nonlinear in their consumption so you might get no visible light at all at 20V, full brightness at 32V and it would burn out at 34V.

The information in the eBay listing is inadequate to describe the unit. You should be aware it will require a large heat sink as well, if you don't want it to quickly degrade and fail at full power.

I think your best bet is to try to determine the voltage and current (ask the seller) and buy a constant-current LED driver- and heat sink- that are appropriate for your 20W LED.

Comment: Thank you! I'm reaching out to them and also looking into alternative power sources. I have a single fan heat sink on hand that will hopefully take care of the cooling.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, before you do anything, you are going to want to set your regulator to constant current mode: turn up the potentiometer (the little dial that controls voltage) to the max setting. Then, with the current potentiometer (the other dial), set that to the minimum current setting. Then, short out the output of the regulator. Turn the current dial up until you're a little under the LED rated limit (say 80%). You now have the regulator configured.

Second, you soldered the wires on the wrong tabs of the COB. The leads should be soldered on those tabs protruding out 90 degrees from where you wired them in your pic. Also, make sure you have the polarity (+ and -) correct - if you hook the red and black leads up the wrong way, you can damage the COB with enough voltage.

Third, after you get that to illuminate, you're going to **need** a heatsink for that guy as it's going to get hot **in a few seconds**. After you get everything mounted and working, you can tweak the current for best performance: more current equals great light output less current equals longer lifetime. This is all assuming your regulator is large enough to power you LED.